# Differentiability of a real valued function on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

So I am trying to understand the following definition,
Let $S$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ and let $\phi=[\xi^1,...,\xi^n]$($\phi:S\to \mathbb{R^n}$) be the coordinate of a point $p\in S$. Let $f: S\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi^i}=\frac{\partial f\circ\phi^{-1}(\xi^1,...,\xi^n)}{\partial \xi^i}\circ\phi$

I have constructed an example and I want to know if it is correct or not,
Let $\mathbb{S^1}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}/ x^2+y^2=1\}$ and let $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{S^1}/y>0\}$ be an open set, Now if I define $\phi: U\to(-1,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(p)=\xi$ (I am defining this since I am assuming we don't know $p\in \mathbb{S^1}$ yet.) So by definition $p=\phi(p)=\xi.$ So my $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ I am defining it as $f(\xi)=\xi^2$. Now we have to find the partial derivative of $f$ ,so by above as we have defined $f\circ \phi^{-1}=\xi^2$ since we have $p=\phi^{-1}(\xi)$ but we know that $p=\xi$ so $\phi^{-1}(\xi)=\xi.$ I wanted to know is my construction is correct till here or not,please someone verify.Thanks

Comment: No it is not. You neither have $p=\phi(p),$ nor $p=\xi,$ nor $\phi^{-1}(\xi)=\xi.$ $p\in U\ne(-1,1)\ni\xi.$ Also, you forgot to define $\phi:U\to(-1,1).$

Comment: then,what mistake I am making please explain.

Comment: Actually, I have studied that if $p\in U$ is a point in the open set of a manifold we define a homomorphism $\phi: U\to \phi(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that is for $p\in U$ we will have $\phi(p)=\{\xi^1,...,\xi^n\}\in \mathbb{R^n}$. and this will be the coordinates of point $p\in U$ that is $p=(\xi^1(p),...,\xi^n(p))$ ,where each $\xi^i:U\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, so $\phi(p)\in\Bbb R^n$ is different from $p\in U.$ And if you want to go further and apply the definition of the differential of your $f,$ you will have to choose an explicit $\phi$ for your example.

Comment: But why as we see that $\phi(p)=(\xi^1(p),...,\xi^n(p))$ and we are saying that coordinates of $p$ are $(\xi^1(p),...,\xi^n(p))$ then how these two are different?

Comment: Please explicit some hom*e*omorphism $\phi:U\to(-1,1)$ and I think you will understand.

Comment: let $\phi(x,y)=x$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140872/discussion-between-anne-bauval-and-andyale).